# Extending Python with C/C++

Tags: c++, python, c

Can anyone please give me tips on the tools or sofware to use to extend Python with C/C++? Thanks.

Comment: When you read http://docs.python.org/c-api/ what problems did you have?

Comment: Cython is a good option for doing this! I actually wrote a small post about it, covering all the details from writing Cython source files to building them, writing setup.py - basicaly all that you need to wrap a C/C++ library with Cython: http://martinsosic.com/development/2016/02/08/wrapping-c-library-as-python-module.html

Answer (score 14):

I'll add the obligatory reference to [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) for C++ stuff.

Comment: I started using boost.python few days ago and I'm already up and running.

Answer (score 13):

The Python website itself has a great [set of examples](http://docs.python.org/extending/), as well as [API documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/). That's literally all I used when I needed to write C extensions.

Comment: oh I thought you meant figuratively, thanks for the clarification

Comment: Hand written code is the best if the libary is not extraordinary large (like QT or WxWidgets).

Answer (score 8):

We use SWIG to wrap our C/C++ libraries for use in Python. It works quite well.

http://www.swig.org/

Answer (score 6):

I see nobody's yet pointed out one of my favorite solutions for wrapping C++ code, [SIP](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/intro) (I believe it also works for wrapping C, like SWIG and unlike Boost, but I've never used it that way). It's the tool Riverbank Software developed to make PyQt, the Python interface to the wonderful Qt C++ cross-platform framework -- so it's a natural choice if your C++ code uses any Qt functionality, just like Boost Python is the natural choice if your C++ code uses Boost.

SWIG is what we use at work (a reasonable decision when it was made 10 years ago;-) and has the theoretical advantage that it can also wrap C or C++ code for use from Java, Perl, Tcl, etc -- but if you only care about Python it's hard to see anything to make it stand out.

If you're just wrapping an existing DLL/so, besides Cython, which other answers have pointed out (and I endorse, but -- it's changing very fast these days, so take care if you need something more stable), consider the standard function module [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) -- I wouldn't use it for very extensive work ("oops" errors that a C or C++ compiler would point out to you can cause runtime crashes with ctypes), but for small jobs it's great (and very handy since it comes with standard Python distributions!-).

The good old C API ain't dead yet - just met today with Case, the great guy who's been doing most of the running lately for my good old open source project [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/), and together we decided to stick with the C API for at least the next release of gmpy -- we'll consider switching to Cython when it stabilizes, but we agreed that the switch would still be a bit premature now. (We didn't even think of any other alternative because gmpy's main point is to be as blindingly fast as we can possibly make it!-).

Comment: What do you think about Siboken, the equivalent for PySide? http://www.pyside.org/docs/shiboken/

Comment: @Craig, haven't tried it yet, I plan to when I next need to do some Qt work (so giving me a realistic chance to try PySide).

Comment: Sorry about the typo, I meant "Shiboken". PySide sounds promising; I'm just sorry they're having to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

There are many solutions. In general, you should avoid it if possible, as writing C extensions is tedious. Often, it is necessary to use a 3rd party library. In that case, I think the winning solution today is [cython](http://www.cython.org/).

Cython is a languages which "looks like python", but can be made much faster by using optional typing. You can call directly C functions inside, and most of the reference counting (the hard problem in C extensions) is done automatically. In my experience, it is much better than boost.python, swig, or ctypes:

- boost.python only makes sense for wrapping C++ extensions IMHO. I find it too complicated, and hard to debug when something goes wrong.
- swig has quite some overhead, and does not lead to good code. It works ok for a couple of functions, but non trivial extensions often use typemaps, and the syntax get ugly quickly

With cython, you can use python objects (list, dict, etc...) to wrap your C library. Of course, it is also very useful if you need to write your own extension just for speed reasons. In the scientific python community, I think cython has become the tool of choice when speed is needed.

Comment: Saying "you should avoid it if possible" without knowing the reasons the OP wants to do it in the first place is misguided. There is a reason Python supports C extensions, and it is because sometimes a C extension is the best solution, in which case it should not be avoided. Also ctypes has a lot of advantages over cython depending on context, without which it's misguided to say one is better (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942298/wrapping-a-c-library-in-python-c-cython-or-ctypes)

Answer (score 3):

I've used [pycxx](http://cxx.sourceforge.net/) in the past and I've really enjoyed to use this lib.

In my opinion, it is easier to use than SWIG. I can't really compare to boost.python because I've never really used boost. I think that pycxx is lighter than boost.python but I may be wrong.

The key point with pycxx is that it is a c++ wrapper of the python c api. It is object-oriented and it hides all the difficult mechanism. It is quite intuitive for a python programmer. It is very easy to use and there is some nice examples for getting started.

I do recommend pycxx as a first-class citizen for making python extension in c++.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need this: http://www.python.org/doc/ext/

And of course also a C/C++ compiler.

If you describe what you are trying to do, and what kind of extensions you are making I'm sure people can give you more info.

There are things like SWIG to wrap libraries, if that's what you want to do. If you just want speedups, C is often the answer, but not always, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised no one has mentioned [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) yet. Pybind11 is [amazing](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/9ei08u/pybind11_is_amazing/)!

From their docs:

> pybind11 is a lightweight header-only library that exposes C++ types in Python and vice versa, mainly to create Python bindings of existing C++ code. Its goals and syntax are similar to the excellent Boost.Python library by David Abrahams: to minimize boilerplate code in traditional extension modules by inferring type information using compile-time introspection.

...

> Think of this library as a tiny self-contained version of Boost.Python with everything stripped away that isn't relevant for binding generation. Without comments, the core header files only require ~4K lines of code and depend on Python (2.7 or 3.x, or PyPy2.7 >= 5.7) and the C++ standard library.

Check pybind11 github repo, there's plenty of info, and a comprehensive list of [features](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11#core-features) and [goodies](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11#goodies).

Documentation with examples can be found [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this example](http://github.com/felipec/libmtag-python/tree/master) helps. I think it's simple enough :)

Answer (score 0):

[Python Bindings: Calling C or C++ From Python](https://realpython.com/python-bindings-overview/#python-bindings-overview) by Jim Anderson Real Python comprehensive set of examples I’ve found for extending Python with C or C++ (or, more generally Python Bindings).

It demonstrates the following options:

- [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ctypes.html)
- [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [PyBind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- [Cython](https://cython.org/)

It includes fully worked out examples for each option along with the sample code to run them.

Other options are also described briefly with no sample code (PyBindGen, Boost.Python, SIP, Cppyy, Shiboken,and SWIG).