# Wrapping a C library in Python: C, Cython or ctypes?

Tags: python, c, ctypes, cython

I want to call a C library from a Python application. I don't want to wrap the whole API, only the functions and datatypes that are relevant to my case. As I see it, I have three choices:

1. Create an actual extension module in C. Probably overkill, and I'd also like to avoid the overhead of learning extension writing.
2. Use [Cython](http://www.cython.org/) to expose the relevant parts from the C library to Python.
3. Do the whole thing in Python, using [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) to communicate with the external library.

I'm not sure whether 2) or 3) is the better choice. The advantage of 3) is that `ctypes` is part of the standard library, and the resulting code would be pure Python – although I'm not sure how big that advantage actually is.

Are there more advantages / disadvantages with either choice? Which approach do you recommend?

---

**Edit:** Thanks for all your answers, they provide a good resource for anyone looking to do something similar. The decision, of course, is still to be made for the single case—there's no one "This is the right thing" sort of answer. For my own case, I'll probably go with ctypes, but I'm also looking forward to trying out Cython in some other project.

With there being no single true answer, accepting one is somewhat arbitrary; I chose FogleBird's answer as it provides some good insight into ctypes and it currently also is the highest-voted answer. However, I suggest to read all the answers to get a good overview.

Thanks again.

Comment: To some extent, the specific application involved (what the library does) may affect the choice of approach.  We've used ctypes quite successfully to talk to vendor-supplied DLLs for various pieces of hardare (e.g. oscilloscopes) but I wouldn't necessarily pick ctypes first for talking to a numeric processing library, because of the extra overhead versus Cython or SWIG.

Comment: Now you have what were you looking for. Four different answers.(somebody also found SWIG). That mean that now you have 4 choices instead of 3.

Comment: @ralu That's what I thougt, too :-) But seriously, I didn't expect (or want) a pro/con table or one single answer saying "Here's what you need to do". Any question about decision making is best answered with "fans" of each possible choice giving their reasons. The community voting then does its part, as does my own work (looking at the arguments, applying them to my case, read provided sources, etc). Long story short: There are some good answers here.

Comment: So which approach are you going to go with? :)

Comment: Still thinking, but leaning heavily towards ctypes.

Comment: As far as I know (please correct me if I'm wrong), Cython is a fork of Pyrex with more development going into it, making Pyrex pretty much obsolete.

Comment: @balpha Maybe you can reflect in your question, that there's [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.org) now (which is superior to ctypes in many ways).

Answer (score 131, accepted):

`ctypes` is your best bet for getting it done quickly, and it's a pleasure to work with as you're still writing Python!

I recently wrapped an [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/) driver for communicating with a USB chip using ctypes and it was great.  I had it all done and working in less than one work day. (I only implemented the functions we needed, about 15 functions).

We were previously using a third-party module, [PyUSB](http://bleyer.org/pyusb/), for the same purpose.  PyUSB is an actual C/Python extension module.  But PyUSB wasn't releasing the GIL when doing blocking reads/writes, which was causing problems for us.  So I wrote our own module using ctypes, which does release the GIL when calling the native functions.

One thing to note is that ctypes won't know about `#define` constants and stuff in the library you're using, only the functions, so you'll have to redefine those constants in your own code.

Here's an example of how the code ended up looking (lots snipped out, just trying to show you the gist of it):

```
from ctypes import *

d2xx = WinDLL('ftd2xx')

OK = 0
INVALID_HANDLE = 1
DEVICE_NOT_FOUND = 2
DEVICE_NOT_OPENED = 3

...

def openEx(serial):
    serial = create_string_buffer(serial)
    handle = c_int()
    if d2xx.FT_OpenEx(serial, OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER, byref(handle)) == OK:
        return Handle(handle.value)
    raise D2XXException

class Handle(object):
    def __init__(self, handle):
        self.handle = handle
    ...
    def read(self, bytes):
        buffer = create_string_buffer(bytes)
        count = c_int()
        if d2xx.FT_Read(self.handle, buffer, bytes, byref(count)) == OK:
            return buffer.raw[:count.value]
        raise D2XXException
    def write(self, data):
        buffer = create_string_buffer(data)
        count = c_int()
        bytes = len(data)
        if d2xx.FT_Write(self.handle, buffer, bytes, byref(count)) == OK:
            return count.value
        raise D2XXException
```

Someone did [some benchmarks](http://tungwaiyip.info/blog/2009/07/16/ctype_performance_benchmark) on the various options.

I might be more hesitant if I had to wrap a C++ library with lots of classes/templates/etc.  But ctypes works well with structs and can even [callback](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions) into Python.

Comment: Joining the praises for ctypes, but do notice one (undocumented) issue: ctypes does not support forking. If you fork from a process using ctypes, and both parent and child processes continue using ctypes, you will stumble upon a nasty bug which has to do with ctypes using shared memory.

Comment: @OrenShemesh Is there any further reading on this issue you can point me to? I think I may be safe with a project I'm currently working on, since I believe only the parent process uses `ctypes` (for `pyinotify`), but I'd like to understand the problem more thoroughly.

Comment: This passage helps me a lot `One thing to note is that ctypes won't know about #define constants and stuff in the library you're using, only the functions, so you'll have to redefine those constants in your own code.` So, I have to define constants which are there in `winioctl.h`....

Comment: how about performance? `ctypes` is much slower than c-extension since the bottleneck is the interface from Python to C

Answer (score 180):

Warning: a Cython core developer's opinion ahead.

I almost always recommend Cython over ctypes. The reason is that it has a much smoother upgrade path. If you use ctypes, many things will be simple at first, and it's certainly cool to write your FFI code in plain Python, without compilation, build dependencies and all that. However, at some point, you will almost certainly find that you have to call into your C library a lot, either in a loop or in a longer series of interdependent calls, and you would like to speed that up. That's the point where you'll notice that you can't do that with ctypes. Or, when you need callback functions and you find that your Python callback code becomes a bottleneck, you'd like to speed it up and/or move it down into C as well. Again, you cannot do that with ctypes. So you have to switch languages at that point and start rewriting parts of your code, potentially reverse engineering your Python/ctypes code into plain C, thus spoiling the whole benefit of writing your code in plain Python in the first place.

With Cython, OTOH, you're completely free to make the wrapping and calling code as thin or thick as you want. You can start with simple calls into your C code from regular Python code, and Cython will translate them into native C calls, without any additional calling overhead, and with an extremely low conversion overhead for Python parameters. When you notice that you need even more performance at some point where you are making too many expensive calls into your C library, you can start annotating your surrounding Python code with static types and let Cython optimise it straight down into C for you. Or, you can start rewriting parts of your C code in Cython in order to avoid calls and to specialise and tighten your loops algorithmically. And if you need a fast callback, just write a function with the appropriate signature and pass it into the C callback registry directly. Again, no overhead, and it gives you plain C calling performance. And in the much less likely case that you really cannot get your code fast enough in Cython, you can still consider rewriting the truly critical parts of it in C (or C++ or Fortran) and call it from your Cython code naturally and natively. But then, this really becomes the last resort instead of the only option.

So, ctypes is nice to do simple things and to quickly get something running. However, as soon as things start to grow, you'll most likely come to the point where you notice that you'd better used Cython right from the start.

Comment: +1 those are good points, thanks a lot! Although I wonder if moving only the bottleneck parts to Cython is really this much of an overhead. But I agree, if you expect any kind of performance issues, you might as well utilize Cython from the beginning.

Comment: Does this still hold for programmers experienced with both C and Python? In that case one may argue that Python/ctypes is the better choice, since the vectorization of C loops (SIMD) is sometimes more straightforward. But, other than that, I cannot think of any Cython drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One thing I had trouble with regarding Cython is getting the build process right (but that also has to do with me never writing a Python module before) - should I compile it before, or include Cython source files in sdist and similar questions. I wrote a blog post about it in case anybody has similar problems/doubts: http://martinsosic.com/development/2016/02/08/wrapping-c-library-as-python-module.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One drawback when I use Cython is that operator overloading is not fully implemented (e.g. `__radd__`). This is especsially annoying when you plan for your class to interact with builtin types (e.g `int` and `float`). Also, magic methods in cython are just a bit buggy in general.

Answer (score 109):

Cython is a pretty cool tool in itself, well worth learning, and is surprisingly close to the Python syntax. If you do any scientific computing with Numpy, then Cython is the way to go because it integrates with Numpy for fast matrix operations.

Cython is a superset of Python language. You can throw any valid Python file at it, and it will spit out a valid C program. In this case, Cython will just map the Python calls to the underlying CPython API. This results in perhaps a 50% speedup because your code is no longer interpreted.

To get some optimizations, you have to start telling Cython additional facts about your code, such as type declarations. If you tell it enough, it can boil the code down to pure C. That is, a for loop in Python becomes a for loop in C. Here you will see massive speed gains. You can also link to external C programs here.

Using Cython code is also incredibly easy. I thought the manual makes it sound difficult. You literally just do:

```
$ cython mymodule.pyx
$ gcc [some arguments here] mymodule.c -o mymodule.so
```

and then you can `import mymodule` in your Python code and forget entirely that it compiles down to C.

In any case, because Cython is so easy to setup and start using, I suggest trying it to see if it suits your needs. It won't be a waste if it turns out not to be the tool you're looking for.

Comment: No problem. The nice thing about Cython is that you can learn only what you need. If you only want a modest improvement, all you have to do is compile your Python files and you're done.

Comment: "You can throw any valid Python file at it, and it will spit out a valid C program." <-- Not quite, there are some limitations: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/limitations.html

Likely not a problem for most use cases, but just wanted to be complete.

Comment: The issues are getting less with each release, to the point that that page now says "most of the issues have been solved in 0.15".

Comment: To add, there is an EVEN easier way to import cython code: write your cython code as a `mymod.pyx` module and then do `import pyximport; pyximport.install(); import mymod` and the compilation happens behind the scenes.

Comment: @kaushik Even simpler is http://pypi.python.org/pypi/runcython. Just use `runcython mymodule.pyx`. And unlike pyximport you can use it for more demanding linking tasks. Only caveat is that I'm the one who wrote the 20 lines of bash for it and might be biased.

Answer (score 43):

For calling a C library from a Python application there is also [**cffi**](http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which is a new alternative for *ctypes*. It brings a fresh look for FFI:

- it handles the problem in a fascinating, clean way (as opposed to *ctypes*)
- it doesn't require to write non Python code (as in *SWIG, Cython*, ...)

Comment: definitely the way to go for *wrapping*, as OP wanted. cython sounds great for writing them hot loops yourself, but for interfaces, cffi simply is a straight upgrade from ctypes.

Answer (score 22):

I'll throw another one out there: [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html)

It's easy to learn, does a lot of things right, and supports many more languages so the time spent learning it can be pretty useful.

If you use SWIG, you are creating a new python extension module, but with SWIG doing most of the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 20):

Personally, I'd write an extension module in C. Don't be intimidated by Python C extensions -- they're not hard at all to write. The documentation is very clear and helpful. When I first wrote a C extension in Python, I think it took me about an hour to figure out how to write one -- not much time at all.

Comment: Wrapping a C library. You can actually find the code here: http://github.com/mdippery/lehmer

Comment: @forivall: The code wasn't really all that useful, and there are better random number generators out there. I only have a backup on my computer.

Comment: Agreed. Python's C-API isn't nearly as scary as it looks (assuming you know C). However, unlike with python and its reservoir of libraries, resources, and developers, when writing extensions in C you're basically on your own. Probably its only drawback (other than the ones that typically come with writing in C).

Comment: @mipadi: well, but they differ between Python 2.x and 3.x, so it's more convenient to use Cython to write your extension, have Cython figure out all the details and then compile the generated C code for Python 2.x *or* 3.x as needed.

Comment: @mipadi it seems like the github link is dead and it doesn't seem available on archive.org, do you have a backup?

Answer (score 12):

If you have already a library with a defined  API, I think `ctypes` is the best option, as you only have to do a little initialization and then more or less call the library the way you're used to.

I think Cython or creating an extension module in C (which is not very difficult) are more useful when you need new code, e.g. calling that library and do some complex, time-consuming tasks, and then passing the result to Python.

Another approach, for simple programs, is directly do a different process (compiled externally), outputting the result to standard output and call it with subprocess module. Sometimes it's the easiest approach.

For example, if you make a console C program that works more or less that way

```
$miCcode 10
Result: 12345678
```

You could call it from Python

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['miCcode', '10'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> std_out, std_err = p.communicate()
>>> print std_out
Result: 12345678
```

With a little string formating, you can take the result in any way you want. You can also capture the standard error output, so it's quite flexible.

Comment: While there is nothing incorrect with this answer, people should be cautious if the code is to be opened up to access by others as calling subprocess with `shell=True` could easily result in some kind of exploit when a user really does get a shell.  It's fine when the developer is the sole user, but out in the world there are a whole bunch of annoying pricks just waiting for something like this.

Answer (score 12):

[ctypes](https://web.archive.org/web/20180404121346/http://python.net:80/crew/theller/ctypes/) is great when you've already got a compiled library blob to deal with (such as OS libraries). The calling overhead is severe, however, so if you'll be making a lot of calls into the library, and you're going to be writing the C code anyway (or at least compiling it), I'd say to go for [cython](https://cython.org/). It's not much more work, and it'll be much faster and more pythonic to use the resulting pyd file.

I personally tend to use cython for quick speedups of python code (loops and integer comparisons are two areas where cython particularly shines), and when there is some more involved code/wrapping of other libraries involved, I'll turn to [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/python/doc/index.html). Boost.Python can be finicky to set up, but once you've got it working, it makes wrapping C/C++ code straightforward.

cython is also great at wrapping [numpy](https://numpy.org/) (which I learned from the [SciPy 2009 proceedings](https://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/SciPy2009/)), but I haven't used numpy, so I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question but this thing comes up on google when you search stuff like `ctypes vs cython`, and most of the answers here are written by those who are proficient already in `cython` or `c` which might not reflect the actual time you needed to invest to learn those to implement your solution. I am a complete beginner in both. I have never touched `cython` before, and have very little experience on `c/c++`.

For the last two days, I was looking for a way to delegate a performance heavy part of my code to something more low level than python. I implemented my code both in `ctypes` and `Cython`, which consisted basically of two simple functions.

I had a huge *string list* that needed to processed. Notice `list` and `string`.
Both types do not correspond perfectly to types in `c`, because python strings are by default unicode and `c` strings are not. Lists in python are simply NOT arrays of c.

Here is my verdict. Use `cython`. It integrates more fluently to python, and easier to work with in general. When something goes wrong `ctypes` just throws you segfault, at least `cython` will give you compile warnings with a stack trace whenever it is possible, and you can return a valid python object easily with `cython`.

Here is a detailed account on how much time I needed to invest in both them to implement the same function. I did very little C/C++ programming by the way:

- Ctypes:

  - About 2h on researching how to transform my list of unicode strings to a c compatible type.
  - About an hour on how to return a string properly from a c function. Here I actually provided my own solution to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59572909/7330813) once I have written the functions.
  - About half an hour to write the code in c, compile it to a dynamic library.
  - 10 minutes to write a test code in python to check if `c` code works.
  - About an hour of doing some tests and rearranging the `c` code.
  - Then I plugged the `c` code into actual code base, and saw that `ctypes` does not play well with `multiprocessing` module as its handler is not pickable by default.
  - About 20 minutes I rearranged my code to not use `multiprocessing` module, and retried.
  - Then second function in my `c` code generated segfaults in my code base although it passed my testing code. Well, this is probably my fault for not checking well with edge cases, I was looking for a quick solution.
  - For about 40 minutes I tried to determine possible causes of these segfaults.
  - I split my functions into two libraries and tried again. Still had segfaults for my second function.
  - I decided to let go of the second function and use only the first function of `c` code and at the second or third iteration of the python loop that uses it, I had a `UnicodeError` about not decoding a byte at the some position though I encoded and decoded everthing explicitely.

At this point, I decided to search for an alternative and decided to look into `cython`:

- Cython

  - 10 min of reading [cython hello world](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#cython-hello-world).
  - 15 min of checking [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528560/using-setuptools-to-create-a-cython-package-calling-an-external-c-library) on how to use cython with `setuptools` instead of `distutils`.
  - 10 min of reading on [cython types](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#types) and python types. I learnt I can use most of the builtin python types for static typing.
  - 15 min of reannotating my python code with cython types.
  - 10 min of modifying my `setup.py` to use compiled module in my codebase.
  - Plugged in the module directly to the `multiprocessing` version of codebase. It works.

For the record, I of course, did not measure the exact timings of my investment. It may very well be the case that my perception of time was a little to attentive due too mental effort required while I was dealing with ctypes. But it should convey the feel of dealing with `cython` and `ctypes`

Answer (score 9):

There is one issue which made me use ctypes and not cython and which is not mentioned in other answers.

Using ctypes the result does not depend on compiler you are using at all. You may write a library using more or less any language which  may be compiled to native shared library. It does not matter much, which system, which language and which compiler. Cython, however, is limited by the infrastructure. E.g, if you want to use intel compiler on windows, it is much more tricky to make cython work: you should "explain" compiler to cython, recompile something with this exact compiler, etc. Which significantly limits portability.

Answer (score 5):

If you are targeting Windows and choose to wrap some proprietary C++ libraries, then you may soon discover that different versions of `msvcrt***.dll` (Visual C++ Runtime) are slightly incompatible.

This means that you may not be able to use [`Cython`](http://www.cython.org/) since resulting `wrapper.pyd` is linked against `msvcr90.dll` *(Python 2.7)* or `msvcr100.dll` *(Python 3.x)*. If the library that you are wrapping is linked against different version of runtime, then you're out of luck.

Then to make things work you'll need to create C wrappers for C++ libraries, link that wrapper dll against the same version of `msvcrt***.dll` as your C++ library. And then use [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to load your hand-rolled wrapper dll dynamically at the runtime.

So there are lots of small details, which are described in great detail in following article:

"Beautiful Native Libraries *(in Python)*": http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/8/18/beautiful-native-libraries/

Comment: That article doesn't have anything to do with the issues you bring up with compatibility of Microsoft compilers. Getting Cython extensions working on Windows really isn't very hard. I've been able to use MinGW for pretty much everything. A good Python distribution helps though.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a possible issue on windows (that I'm currently having as well...). @IanH it's less about windows in general, but it's a mess if you're stuck with a given third party lib that doesn't match your python distribution.

Answer (score 3):

There's also one possibility to use [GObject Introspection](http://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection) for libraries that are using [GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/).