# Python wrapper for libfprint

Tags: python, wrapper

Where can I find a Python wrapper for libprint? If such wrapper does not exist, is it possible to write one? How can I get started?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942298/wrapping-a-c-library-in-python-c-cython-or-ctypes

Comment: Do you mean this [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint) library?

Comment: @martincho :  Have you done this. I am also want to do the same thing. I hope you can help me.

Comment: @Kukku: this was a long time ago unfortunately. I don't remember very well. Take a look at the second answer of this question. You can always write a small executable in C++ and call it from Python with popen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint) (I hope it is the project you are looking for) is using GLib, you might want to look into [GObject Introspection](http://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection).

Answer (score 5):

I also made a lot of search for this, and I did learn a lot of C/C++ while trying to use *libfprint* as it is, but someday, out of nowhere, I saw [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407850/check-a-fingerprint-in-the-database) some guy posted here and voilà:

https://github.com/luksan/pyfprint

Comment: pyfprint has problems in its implementation of identification of fingers (scanned finger versus gallery of stored fingerprints), so I decided to tweak the C API anyway. Maybe someday, with a bit of luck, I'll released a full-fledged all-working Python module for libfprint.

Comment: is this tested one?.  I was searching for the same.

Comment: It has been update recently, @Kukku, after many years, and it is now compatible with Python3. I didn't test it after the update, but it seems solid.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the @plaes's answer it's possible to use libfprint (or libfprint-2) from Python with GObject Introspection (GI).

You should have the correct packages installed. In Ubuntu 20.04, I installed `python3-gi`:

```
sudo apt install python3-gi
```

And then you can use the library like this from the python3 shell:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('FPrint', '2.0')
from gi.repository import FPrint, GLib

dir(FPrint)
```

In the dir result you'll see the exported names available. Refer to libfprint API documentation for usage: https://fprint.freedesktop.org/libfprint-dev/

Here's a simple example to get started:

```
ctx = FPrint.Context()
devices = ctx.get_devices()
print([dev.get_name() for dev in devices])
```

Note that there is also a D-Bus API available to fprintd: https://fprint.freedesktop.org/fprintd-dev/ref-dbus.html