# Using setuptools to create a cython package calling an external C library

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

I am trying to compile, install and run a package that we'll call `myPackage`. It contains a `*.pyx` file that calls the function `fftw_set_timelimit()` from library `fftw`. Currently, when I run a script `clientScript.py` that imports the package I obtain the following error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clientScript.py", line 5, in <module>
    import myPackage.myModule
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/myPackage/myModule.so: undefined symbol: fftw_set_timelimit
```

From what I understand (I am quite new to python and cython), the linking with the C library is not yet performed in my package. Indeed, my `setup.py` file looks like this :

```
from setuptools   import setup,find_packages
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os

setup(
    name = "myPackage",
    version = "0.0.1",
    url = "none",
    author = "me",
    author_email = "me@me.me",
    packages=find_packages(),
    ext_modules = cythonize("pyClo/pyClo.pyx"),
)
```

As you can see my `setup.py` file uses `setuptools`. I decided to do so since it is recommended by the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current.html). However, the instructions in the [Cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) use `distutils` instead. Linking libraries is done through a call to `distutils.Extension('file',['file.pyx'],libraries='fftw')`. How do I achieve the same result using `setuptools` ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It turns out `setuptools` has a module `setuptools.extension.Extension` which is used in the same way as the `distutils.extension.Extension` module .

In the end, the `setup.py` file looks something like :

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension(
        "myPackage.myModule",
        ["myPackage/myModule.pyx"],
        include_dirs=['/some/path/to/include/'], # not needed for fftw unless it is installed in an unusual place
        libraries=['fftw3', 'fftw3f', 'fftw3l', 'fftw3_threads', 'fftw3f_threads', 'fftw3l_threads'],
        library_dirs=['/some/path/to/include/'], # not needed for fftw unless it is installed in an unusual place
    ),
]

setup(
    name = "myPackage",
    packages = find_packages(),
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
)
```

Here is an overview of my installation directory :

```
.
├── MANIFEST.in
├── myPackage
│   └── myModule.pyx
├── README.rst
└── setup.py
```

where `myModule.pyx` is the file that calls `fftw_set_timelimit()`.

`MANIFEST.in` contains :

```
include myPackage/*.*
```

and `README.rst` is a mere plain text file.

Comment: According to [distutils documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension), `distutils.core.Extension` takes as a first argument : 

"_the full name of the extension, including any packages — ie. not a filename or pathname, but Python dotted name_"

Therefore, instead of `"myPackage/myModule"`, one should have `"myPackage.myModule"`.

Comment: @SylM I haven't been using python in a while now… So it's going to be some effort for me to double check that replacing the slash "/" by a point "." as you are suggesting indeed works. However if you test the solution and tell me it's ok, then I'll edit my answer accordingly. By "testing the solution" I mean starting a new project from scratch and making sure you can make it work. Would you like to do that ? ;)

Comment: @GLorieul I have just used the above template using the dotted name syntax, and successfully compiled.

Comment: @Gilly thanks! I updated my answer accordingly : can you double check that the edit I made is correct please?