# python setuptools: how can I install package with cython submodules?

Tags: python, cython, setuptools

I have a python package named [pytools](https://github.com/zeakey/pytools).
It contains a cython-based submodule [nms](https://github.com/zeakey/pytools/nms).

When I install the root package pytools with `sudo python -H setup.py`,
the root package seems to be installed properly.

But the installation didn't copy compiled `nms.so` to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytools/nms/`.

And When I import pytools in ipython, an error encountered:

> ImportError: cannot import name nms

If I manually copy the `pytools/nms/nms.so` to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytools/nms/`, the problem is solved.

Here is my `setup.py` of the root package:

```
import os
import numpy
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

exec(open('pytools/version.py').read())
exts = [Extension(name='nms',
                  sources=["_nms.pyx", "nms.c"],
                  include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
        ]
setup(name='pytools',
  version=__version__,
  description='python tools',
  url='http://kaiz.xyz/pytools',
  author_email='zhaok1206@gmail.com',
  license='MIT',
  packages=['pytools', 'pytools.nms'],
  #packages=['pytools'],
  zip_safe=False
)
```

And `setup.py` of sub-package `nms`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import numpy
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
setup(
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=[Extension("nms",
    sources=["_nms.pyx", "nms.c"],
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])],
)
```

It seems that this is a duplicated question with [Attempting to build a cython extension to a python package, not creating shared object (.so) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875043/attempting-to-build-a-cython-extension-to-a-python-package-not-creating-shared), but I still want to post it here because there is no much discussions there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the setup script in a subpackage. Just build the extension in the root setup script:

```
exts = [Extension(name='pytools.nms',
                  sources=["pytools/nms/_nms.pyx", "pytools/nms/nms.c"],
                  include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])]

setup(
    ...
    packages=['pytools'],
    ext_modules=cythonize(exts)
)
```

Note that I wrap cythonized extension in `cythonize()` and use the full module name + full paths to extension sources. Also, since `nms` is a module in `pytools` package, including `pytools.nms` in `packages` has no effect.

Comment: Hi hoefling, thanks for your answering! But I have another question after doing as you suggested. The generated .so file is located at `build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pytools/nms.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, I cannot import t in `pytools/pytools/nms/__init__.py`. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Do you really need the `nms` package if it contains nothing but the `nms` extension? Of course, it's possible to place the extension in the package, so its import becomes `import pytools.nms.nms.nms_func`, but is it really necessary? Remember, [_flat is better than nested_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Or, make `nms` to a separate python distribution (with own setup script), build the `nms` extension there and let `pytools` depend on `nms` package (via `install_requires` keyword in `pytools`' setup script).

Comment: Tell me what architecture you envision for `pytools` and I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: For deeper placement of the `nms` extension, it should suffice to add `pytools.nms` to the `packages` list and adapt the extension name to `pytools.nms.nms`.

Comment: It seems to be solved since I add 'packages: ['pytools', 'pytools/nms']' into `setup.py`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure it does solve the problem? Because `pytools/nms` is not a valid package name.

Comment: @hoefling, you may be able to help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50448026/4080129