# Cython attemps to compile twice, and fails

Tags: python, compilation, cython, setup.py

I have a `setup.py` file that is very similar to the one shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866324/4080129. It looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

sources = ["hs/subfolder/detect.pyx",
           "hs/subfolder/Donline.cpp",
           "hs/subfolder/Handler.cpp",
           "hs/subfolder/Process.cpp",
           "hs/subfolder/Filter.cpp",
           "hs/subfolder/Localize.cpp"]

exts = [Extension(name='hs.detect',
                  sources=sources,
                  extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11', '-O3'],
                  include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(exts),
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

There's a package with some pure-Python, and a submodule that contains Cython files. The `setup.py` is in the parent folder, not in the Cython one:

```
setup.py
hs/
    some_python.py
    subfolder/
        detect.pyx
        Donline.cpp
        ...etc
```

Now, setup.py correctly compiles all the files `module/submodule/file1.cpp` etc. and saves the build to `build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/module/submodule/file1.o` .
However, just after that, it tries to compile a file called `file1.cpp`, which doesn't exist (the correct one is `module/submodule/file1.cpp`, and has already been compiled).

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ihs/subfolder -I/[...]/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/[...]/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/[...]/include -I/disk/scratch/miniconda/envs/my_default/include/python3.6m -c Donline.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/Donline.o -std=c++11 -O3
gcc: error: Donline.cpp: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
```

I'm very confused, this completely prevents my code from compiling...

Comment: Please share the setup script, also it helps if you provide the project structure on disk (what files in what dirs, w/o contents).

Comment: Done. Thank you!

Comment: The setup script looks good to me, also can't reproduce the issue. Maybe do a clean rebuild? `python setup.py clean build` or just remove the `build/` dir.  Is the error still there?

Comment: Yes, I tried that already.

Comment: I also just tried *not* using the virtualenv, and it's the same. This is really really odd. Could it be the C files calling each other? Or something wrong in the __init__ files? I can't think of a reason...

Comment: Wait, how do you include i.e. `SpkDonline.cpp` in other sources, by just filename? Also, it's cleaner to create a header file for each source file and include those instead of the source files.

Comment: The files reference each other by calling the headers. For example detect.pyx includes the line `cdef extern from "SpkDonline.h"`.

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious of your module name `herdingspikes.detect` - I wonder if Cython is expecting it to be `herdingspikes.detection_localization.detect`. I haven't tested it though, and I'm not sure why it should give that error

Comment: @DavidW I've tried both

Comment: Only other thing I can see here is that you haven't told Cython that `language="c++"`. That's another guess I'm afraid (and I don't see why it'd give _that_ error), but it might be worth a try

Comment: I think I had a previous version of setup.py which had that. Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity - if you provide the absolute path of `SpkDonline.cpp` in the `sources` list, does the error still emerge for `SpkDonline.cpp`? Also, can you paste the full build log?

Comment: I tried with the full path and it didn't help. The full log is too long to paste at the moment, are you looking for anything in particular?

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE please](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is not enough information to replicate the issue.

Comment: Just solved, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the `.pyx` file contains a line

```
# distutils: sources = Donline.cpp Handler.cpp Process.cpp Filter.cpp Localize.cpp
```

which tells distutils what to compile. I wasn't aware of it, and since it looks an awful lot like a commented-out line, I didn't realise it was there.

Cython tries to compile *also* these, other than the ones contained in the `setup.py`file, i.e. neither of the two sources list overrides the other. Apparently, these sources, despite being listed in the pyx file, which is in a subfolder, are expected to be in paths relative to the file where the `setup.py` file is, or perhaps relative to the folder I'm calling python from.

Anyway, removing the line solved the issue.