# Python packaging: different methods to specify external requirements - differences, advantages, and recommendations

Tags: python, deployment, cython, setup.py, python-packaging

I am packaging a python project and look for the "right" way to specify dpendencies on external files. I am aware of multiple ways to specify dpendencies, but I would like to know how these ways work practically, how they differ, and at which specific time points they are taking effect, respectively.

**Known ways to specify dependencies** (see [here](https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_py.html#handling-requirements))

1. We could specify the dependency in the `install_requires` argument of `setuptools.setup`
2. We could use `requirements.txt`
3. We could use `setup.cfg`

**My main questions**

1. What are advantages and disadvantages of the different methods?
2. When and in which order are the information in the respective files read? Would e.g. pip first execute `setup.py` and then check the `requirements.txt` afterwards?
3. What happens if I specify a requirement only in one of the ways given above? What happens, if I speciefy different requirements with different ways?

**Motivating example**

I need to create a package that uses `cython` and `numpy`. As can be seen e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528560/using-setuptools-to-create-a-cython-package-calling-an-external-c-library), `cython` (and similarly `numpy`, must be imported before `setuptools.setup` is called. Hence, `setup.py` would raise an `ImportError` if the library is not available. How would I make the requirement visible anyway so that the necessary packages are installed *before* `setup.py` is called? Should I move the compilation to a different file that is then called from `setup.py`? How would I do that?

Comment: This probably solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/54117786/5769463

Comment: @ead Thank you for pointing me to that link. This might solve my particular problem. Nonetheless, I would be interested in understanding the whole process better. Hence, I am looking for answers of the more general questions as well.

Comment: This platform is not really meant to answer such a question which is actually multiple broad questions in one. It's much better to ask multiple focused questions separately instead. `install_requires` and `requirements.txt` serve different purposes, even though there is overlap. For [Cython with setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#distributing-extensions-compiled-with-cython).

Comment: @sinoroc I appreciate your effort to keep this platform clean and with well-fitting questions only. I have seen (and benefitted from) similar questions on SO, though. I am interested in a comparison between the requirement specifications. I have not found a source with this information. In your link, e.g., no information is given what a `*.toml` file is and what purposes it suits. I may be able to implement that but woud not have a clue what I am doing. I would like to understand.

Comment: A full answer would be rather long and most likely inevitably too opinionated. We could use the comments to figure out more focused questions together. For example asking clarifications about the cython with setuptools issue is a valid, independent, and interesting question (the answer would be about [PEP518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/)). `install_requires` vs. `requirements.txt` is also a valid question but already answered multiple times I believe, a good introduction might be this: https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are many broad questions. It is difficult to give an exhaustive answer and to keep opinions aside...

---

When it comes strictly to packaging Python projects, I believe *pip*'s "*requirements*" files are not commonly useful nor used (there are counter examples of course, but I would argue that they are not a good idea for packaging in general). But in some other use cases, I believe they are very helpful.

If *setuptools* is used for packaging (there are perfectly valid alternatives), then `install_requires` is the way to go to declare the direct dependencies of the project. Unless there is no other way around, then I would recommend placing the whole *setuptools* configuration (this includes `install_requires`) in the `setup.cfg` file instead of as arguments to `setuptools.setup()`. The result would be exactly the same in both cases but (as it is now commonly accepted) for configuration, a static declarative file is a much more natural fit than executable code. As for the order of precedence, I believe a `setuptools.setup()` argument would override the same configuration item read from `setup.cfg`.

> Would e.g. pip first execute `setup.py` and then check the `requirements.txt` afterwards?

These are two different things. The *requirements* file is more or less a list of projects that one wants to install. Each of these projects might be packaged (*setuptools* or other) and distributed (source or pre-built *wheel*) in different ways, some will require the execution of a `setup.py` some won't. But again, when packaging (and distributing) a project there is usually no need to bother with a *requirements* file (never when the project is a library, and not at first when the project is an application, see [Donald Stufft's article "setup.py vs requirements.txt"](https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/)).

I would rather not go into details regarding the question about the combination of *Cython* and *setuptools*. It would be a good additional question. These two links might help get you started though:

- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#distributing-extensions-compiled-with-cython
- https://medium.com/@grassfedcode/pep-517-and-518-in-plain-english-47208ca8b7a6