# Calling C++ DLLs from Python

Tags: ctypes

I'd like to know if it is possible to use ctypes to access C++ DLLs from Python and run functions (or class methods) from them.If not, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending Python with C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076300/extending-python-with-c-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question has been answered [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=swig+python) ([this one is an exact duplicate!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076300/extending-python-with-c-c))

In summary, no you can't do it with Ctypes (yet) but there are a number of other code generators you could use to do the job. [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) and [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) are two of the most popular.

Comment: I don't consider that a proper answer. When one has a compiled DLL, it is not to *extend* Python. It is just to load this DLL in memory and call its imported methods. SWIG and Boost.Python is not about that

Answer (score 1):

the boost python library makes it REALLY easy to wrap a C++ class and expose it as python module. It took me around 10 minutes the first time I tried.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html

Comment: I wasn't so lucky: C1083 Cannot open include file: 'pyconfig.h': No such file or directory EquityCalculatorMontecarlo C:\Users\dickr\git\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\python\detail\wrap_python.hpp 57